# Python - better approach than if else

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I'm trying to improve my old code and wonder if there are better approaches can handle the following example:

Utilizing api to get the search results. The results include different issue severity and I want to get the individual counts and append each case in a list by severity.

In the current code, I can do this way:

```
sev = dict()
sev_list = list()
sev_list_2 = list()
sev_list_3 = list()

for i in search_result:
    issue_key = i.key
    issue_severity = i.severity.name

    if issue_severity == 'Sev_1':
        sev_list.append(issue_key)
        sev_count = len(sev_list)
        sev[issue_severity] = (sev_list, sev_count)
    elif issue_severity == 'Sev_2':
        sev_list_2.append(issue_key)
        sev_count = len(sev_list_2)
        sev[issue_severity] = (sev_list_2, sev_count)
    elif issue_severity == 'Sev_3':
        sev_list_3.append(issue_key)
        sev_count = len(sev_list_3)
        sev[issue_severity] = (sev_list_3, sev_count)
```

outcome:

```
{'Sev_1': (['issue_1', 'issue_4', 'issue_5'], 3), 'Sev_2': (['issue_2', 'issue_3', 'issue_6', 'issue_7'], 4), 'Sev_3': (['issue_8'], 1)}
```

While this is working fine, it's not the best way as it's hard to scale when there are multiple severities exist.

I'm thinking something like this but I'm not sure what's the right way to append if I'd like to use this method. Any other suggestions are appreciated as well.

```
sev = dict()
sev_list = list

for i in query_result:
    issue_key = i.key
    issue_severity = i.severity.name

    severity_list = ['Sev_1', 'Sev_2', 'Sev_3']

    for x in severity_list:
        if issue_severity == x:
            sev_list.append(bug_key)
            sev_count = len(sev_list)
            sev[x] = (sev_list, sev_count)
```

Comment: This seems to be more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will do the work.

```
sev = dict()
for i in search_result:
    issue_key = i.key
    issue_severity = i.severity.name
    if issue_severity in sev:
        sev[issue_severity][0].append(issue_key)
        sev[issue_severity][1] +=1
    else:
        sev[issue_severity] = ([issue_key], 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So since you are already thinking of adding another loop to reduce complexity, I would suggest using dictionary comprehension here

```
# Initialize the empty dict.
sev = {sev_level:([], 0) for sev_level in ['Sev_1', 'Sev_2', 'Sev_3']}

# Fill the items
for i in search_result:
    sev[i.key][0].append(i.severity.name)
    sev[i.key][1] += 1
```